# Find gitignore file and line causing a file to be ignored by git

Tags: git

How can I find the gitignore file and line that is causing a file to be ignored by git?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the repo root, try this:

```
find . ~/.gitignore .git/info/exclude -name '*gitignore' -exec cat {} + | less
```

Also check that you're not using a different excludes file:

```
git config -l | grep exclude
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
```

You [can also get that error when you have submodules in a subfolder instead at the git project's root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11749515/79125).

Thanks to [Jon Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851273/jon-lin) and [Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877115/christopher) for helping me figure this out on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11749515/79125).

Comment: The only way I know of to find the line is to binary search. (Remove half the excludes, see if it's still ignored, ...)

Comment: In my case the second command found the culprit, it seems like the default version of core.excludesfile ignores 'tags', at least as installed by boxen. This was causing a lot of confusion for us when trying to add new JSTL .tag files.

Comment: Saviour! For anyone using Cloud9 IDE, I found you need to go one level up to ~/.gitignore. Because you start off in ~/workspace/, which meant you might not spot the .gitignore. This .gitignore in the home dir had tons of default ignores I did not set, which were causing chaos for me.